# Возможна ли гонка данных при асинхронном IO в одном потоке?

Tags: winapi, асинхронность, race-condition

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. При работе с WinAPI приходится использовать функции [`ReadFileEx()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfileex) и [`WriteFileEx()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefileex) с последующим ожиданием в [`SleepEx()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleepex) для асинхронных операций ввода-вывода. Оправданы ли опасения, что в однопоточной программе с асинхронными операциями возможна гонка данных? Если да, то как с этим бороться?

Comment: Возможна. Достаточно не допускать пересечения пишущихся и читающихся регионов файлов и пересечения буферов, использующихся для этих операций.

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо!